# Update RHEL 5.1 to 5.4

Tags: linux, upgrade, enterprise, redhat

I have a server currently running RHEL 5.1, and I would like to upgrade it to RHEL 5.4. The server is not connected to the Internet, so I don't think I can use "yum update".

How would I be able to upgrade my server, and is it just a small-scale upgrade, like Windows patches, leaving everything on the server intact, or would it delete everything that was on the server?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this myself, but you should be able to use an installation disc for RHEL 5.4 to upgrade even if you are off-line (although you'll need to get on-line somewhere to download the disk image).  Once you have the RHEL 5.4 disc, you should be able to follow the instructions here:

[How do I use yum to update or install packages for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 from a customized repository?](http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-9893)

to update your system.  Basically, you create a custom repository on you hard drive with the rpm files from the disk and point yum at it or use the disc directly.

Good luck.

Of course if you can put the server temporarily on-line and just use the on-line repositories, after updating all the packages in your 5.1 distribution, you'll have all the same files as if you installed 5.4.  At least that's what I remember happening.  I had a 5.0 installation that I kept updated and when I compared them they seemed to be the same as the 5.3 version (current at the time) although during boot, my system said it was still 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Rayne,

I used to work on DOE classified systems that could never touch the public internet. There is a very easy way to do this as mentioned. Just use the ISO as a repo, and for my example to work, it needs to be a DVD image. (The way around that using disk {1,2,3} is to copy the files from each disk onto the local disk or a storage device)

```
You will need to install createrepo which for me involved two dependencies.  

createrepo
deltarpm
python-deltarpm   

mkdir -p /mnt/iso/rhel54
mount -o loop /path/to/rhel5.4.iso /mnt/iso/rhel54
cd /mnt/iso
createrepo .
```

It will look like this:
[root@hostname iso]# createrepo .

44/20586 - rhel54/HighAvailability/Packages/PyQt4-4.6.2-8.el6.x86_64.rpm

```
Create /etc/yum.repos.d/rayne.repo and add 

[Rayne-repo]
baseurl=file:///mnt/iso/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

Then run yum update
```

The update from RHEL 5.1 to RHEL 5.4 is not a small one, not like Windows patches. You can read the release notes, but you will end up with a newer kernel in the end and a ton of updates to the packages. I have not upgraded from 5.X to 5.Y+3 before, it's always been incremental (5.1 to 5.2). At any rate, this should work for you.